# Sample echo error in my site

Tags: php

i have this code:

```
<?php if(@$_GET['show']){ echo $_GET['show']; } ?>
```

and this is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\echo\index.php on line 1
```

What the problem?

Comment: remove the `@` from your code!

Comment: When there are multiple occurrences of a potential issue, it's a good idea to put them on separate lines so your error message makes more sense.

Comment: @alfasin The `@` is presumably just to suppress the "Bad index" warning. How would it help with this error?

Comment: @Barmar if the warning will not be suppressed he might be able to find the problem ;)

Comment: `@` only suppresses runtime errors. He's getting a parse error, so the `@` is irrelevant.

Comment: I suspect there's something in the code that didn't get copied here, maybe a non-printing character. As posted, it shouldn't cause a syntax error.

Comment: The first comment is not relevant here and does not answer the question. Adding a `'@'` suppresses error messages, and does not produce a `Parse error`. I'm going with @Barmar's opinion above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried it locally and no error here.

By the way, instead of trying to suppress any error messages using the `@` sign, you might want to do a real check on the variable. Read on why it's bad [right from the source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

I assume you want to prevent error when the value of `$_GET['show']` is not set. In that case, you should use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if (isset ($_GET['show'])) { echo $_GET['show']; }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Did it produce any error, or it simply didn't work? Can you post the value of `var_dump($_GET);` for us? Preferably in your original posting.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to error suppress (in other words, using `@`) `$_GET`?  You really shouldn't suppress errors anywhere.

Instead, just:

```
<?php if (!empty($_GET['show'])) { echo $_GET['show']; } ?>
```

Comment: You don't need `isset` if you check for `!empty`.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. And someone else has already made this comment.

Comment: @Barmar It provides a solution to his problem.  Ergo, it's an answer